# Constructing a shared_ptr in a for loop and move assignment

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, shared-ptr, move-constructor

I'm trying to get my head around shared pointers at the moment and how they work. I would be really grateful for any advice you could give on the below.

Please could you advise on:

- When to use std::move in make_shared
- What the shared pointer points to if it is constructed using make_shared on an object which is constructed using emplace_back and some user input and that object then disappears from scope e.g. in a for loop I write,

```
vector_declared_outside_for_loop.emplace_back(std::make_shared(object(std::string user_input)))
```

, what happens to the shared_ptr in the for loop after the for loop ends?

- If I now make a vector of pairs of the shared_ptrs from vector_declared_outside_for_loop and some other variable such as int number_input in a subsequent for loop eg.

```
std::vector<std::pair<shared_ptr<object>, int>> new_vector;

    for(int i{0}; i<.size(); ++i){

   new_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(shared_ptr<object> vector_declared_outside_for_loop [i], int connection_type));

   }
```

Do the shared_ptrs in new_vector point to anything? Or am I just pushing new_vector back?

Comment: Don't think of a `shared_ptr` as "pointing to" an object, think of it as *being* an object that can be shared. It behaves exactly like any other C++ object. `make_shared<T>(arguments)` is almost the same as `shared_ptr<T>(new T(arguments))`, but safer and ore efficient.

Comment: A [mre] might help explain your question

Answer (score 0):

- You use `std::move` whenever you have a named object that you no longer use. Just forget all you think you know about `std::move` and learn one simple rule: `std::move` means: *I no longer need this (name object)*.
  So `func1(std::move(func2(...)))` makes no sense. The returned object has no name, there is no way for you to use it again. The compiler knows that and will already use move semantic without `std::move`. Saying *I no longer need this* is pointless because after the `func1` call the temporary object no longer exists.
- make_shared allocates a new object to point to and constructs it in place. But then when you `emplace_back` what you are emplacing is the shared_ptr, not the object it points to. So what happens is that `shared_ptr` is constructed in place inside the `vector` with a pointer to the object it alloctes and constructs.
  The `shared_ptr` in the for loop doesn't exist at all. That's the point of the `emplace_back` that it doesn't create a temporary object but constructs the object in-place inside the vector directly.
- `push_back` normally takes an object and copies it into the vector. So you would create a temporary object, copy it and destroy the temporary. But the STL isn't stupid and covers this case too. If you `push_back` an object that can be moved then it is forwarded to `emplace_back`. So again the pair will be constructed directly in-place inside the vector.
  That leaves the `vector_declared_outside_for_loop`. Since it is an existing object it can't be constructed in-place. Since it is a named object it can not be moved. So the objects will be copied.

  For a `shared_ptr` that means the internal pointer will be copied and the reference count for the object will be incremented atomically. So at the end of the loop the `shared_ptr` will have a reference count of `.size() + 1`. Then at the end of the scope the original `shared_ptr` goes out of scope reducing the reference count by 1. The object used in the vector remains.

Comment: In the third point, you mentioned the original shared_ptr goes out of scope. I am taking this to mean that the shared_ptr from vector_declared_outside_for_loop gets deleted. However, the shared_ptr in new_vector remains. If so, why does the shared_ptr from vector_declared_outside_for_loop get deleted? Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: The shared_ptr is a class like any other. If you declare a shared_ptr in a block of code then it gets destroyed at the end of the scope, at the `}`. That's just like every other object. But the thing the shared_ptr points to only gets destroyed when all copies of a shared_ptr are destroyed. That's the semantic of the shared_ptr.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way for shared_ptr to not be destroyed here?

Comment: No. And you don't want it to. It's doing the right thing.